# Algoritmo de Gauss para la matriz inversa

Tags: python, matrices

Estoy aprendiendo Python y recientemente he visto listas y bucles for. Sabiendo eso me he puesto a intentar escribir un programa que me calcule la matriz inversa de una dada (mediante listas). El algoritmo que me ha quedado es el siguiente:

```
# Datos iniciales

A = [[1,1,-1],[0,1,3],[0,0,1]]
m = len(A)
n = len(A[0])

m1 = m-1
n2 = n*2

if m != n:
    print("Error: La matriz no es cuadrada. Por tanto, no es invertible.")

else:
    
    # Construcción de la matriz identidad
    
    I = []
    for i in range(m):
        I.append([])
        for j in range(n):
            if i == j:
                I[i].append(1)
            else:
                I[i].append(0)
        
        # Matriz (A|I)
        
        A[i]+=I[i]
    
    for i in range(m):
        print(A[i])
    print("")

    # Algoritmo - Triangularización superior

    for j in range(n):
        
        # Búsqueda de pivote
        
        l = [i for i in range(m) if A[i][j] !=0 and i>=j]
        if len(l) == 0:
            print("Error: La matriz no es invertible.")
        else:
            j0 = l[0]
            a = A[j]
            b = A[j0]
            A[j] = b
            A[j0] = a

            # Triangularización superior

            for i in [i for i in range(j+1,m) if A[i][j] != 0]:
                alpha = -A[i][j]/A[j][j]
                for k in range(n2):
                    A[i][k] += A[j][k]*alpha
    
    for i in range(m):
        print(A[i])
    print("")

    # Algoritmo - Triangularización inferior

    for j in range(1,m):
        for i in range(m1):
            alpha = -A[i][j]/A[j][j]
            for k in range(i+1,n2):
                A[i][k] += A[j][k]*alpha

    for i in range(m):
        print(A[i])
    print("")

    # Algoritmo - Transformación a la matriz identidad

    for i in range(m):
        for j in range(n2):
            A[i][j] /= A[i][i]

    for i in range(m):
        print(A[i])
    print("")
```

La parte hasta triangulación superior si uno ejecuta el programa sale lo que tiene que salir. Sin embargo al hacer la triangularización inferior da fallo. El resultado que aparece como matriz inversa tiene una fila llena de ceros lo cual no es posible. ¿Alguien podría decirme qué he escrito mal?

Gracias.

Comment: El método de Gauss se puede implementar de distintas maneras. Si le agregas comentario al código sería más entendible. Me cuesta seguir lo que haces, aún teniendo el método general a la vista. Ponle nombres significativos a las variables, como `num_filas` e `i_fila`

Answer (score 0):

Hay varios problemas. He aquí uno:

```
# Algoritmo - Transformación a la matriz identidad

for i in range(m):
    for j in range(n2):
        A[i][j] /= A[i][i]
```

Si tienes una línea como

```
[0, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

la idea es dividirla para que el primer valor sea `1` en lugar de `5`. El error está en que para cada división ocupas el valor de `A[i][i]`, que va a cambiar tan pronto proceses la columna 2.

La solución es usar como divisor el valor original:

```
# Algoritmo - Transformación a la matriz identidad

for i in range(m):
    factor = A[i][i]
    for j in range(n2):
        A[i][j] /= factor
```

Esto no soluciona el problema general. Para investigarlo hice una pequeña refactorización del código, proceso durante el cual llegue al resultado correcto. Supongo que hay otro error oculto.

Hice algunas optimizaciones. Por ejemplo, al buscar el pivote se elige la línea con el menor valor absoluto en la columna correspondiente. Asi el factor de ajuste (`alpha`) será siempre mayor que 1, *which is nice*.

También agregue `print` para revisar el proceso interno, y puse nombres de variables significativos, además de simplificar algunas operaciones:

```
def imprimir(A, titulo):
    print(titulo)
    for fila in A:
        for value in fila:
            print(f"{value:6.2f} ", end="")
        print()
    print("")


def inversion(A):
    num_filas = len(A)
    num_cols = len(A[0])

    m1 =  - 1
    n2 = num_cols * 2

    if num_filas != num_cols:
        print("Error: La matriz no es cuadrada. Por tanto, no es invertible.")
        return None

    # Construcción de la matriz A | I
    for idx_fila in range(num_filas):
        A[idx_fila] += [1 if idx_fila == j else 0 for j in range(num_filas)]

    imprimir(A, "Matriz ampliada inicial:")

    # Algoritmo - Triangularización superior

    for idx_col in range(num_cols):
        # Búsqueda de pivote
        print(f"Procesando columna {idx_col}")
        l = [(abs(A[idx_fila][idx_col]), idx_fila) for idx_fila in range(idx_col, num_filas) if A[idx_fila][idx_col] != 0]
        if len(l) == 0:
            print("Error: La matriz no es invertible.")
            return None

        idx_fila = min(l)[1]
        if idx_fila != idx_col:
            print(f"Intercambiar fila {idx_fila} con {idx_col}")
            A[idx_col], A[idx_fila] = A[idx_fila],  A[idx_col]
            imprimir(A, "Matriz intercambiada")

        # Triangularización superior
        for idx_fila in [idx for idx in range(idx_col + 1, num_filas) if A[idx][idx_col] != 0]:
            alpha = -A[idx_fila][idx_col] / A[idx_col][idx_col]
            print(f"Ajuste para fila {idx_fila} es {alpha}")
            for k in range(n2):
                A[idx_fila][k] += A[idx_col][k] * alpha
            imprimir(A, "Matriz ajustada")

    imprimir(A, "Matriz triangulación superior")

    # Algoritmo - Triangularización inferior

    for idx_col in range(1, num_cols):
        print(f"Procesando columna {idx_col}")
        for idx_fila in range(idx_col):
            alpha = -A[idx_fila][idx_col] / A[idx_col][idx_col]
            print(f"Fila {idx_fila}, factor {alpha}")
            for k in range(idx_col, n2):
                A[idx_fila][k] += A[idx_col][k] * alpha
            imprimir(A, "Ajustada")

    imprimir(A, "Matriz triangulación inferior")
    # Algoritmo - Transformación a la matriz identidad

    for idx_fila in range(num_filas):
        alpha = A[idx_fila][idx_fila]
        for idx_col in range(idx_fila, n2):
            A[idx_fila][idx_col] /= alpha

    imprimir(A, "Matriz identidad")

    inversa = []
    for fila in A:
        inversa.append(fila[num_cols:])

    return inversa

test1 = [[9, 3, 4], [4, 3, 4], [1, 1, 1]]
x = inversion(test1)
imprimir(x, "Inversa")
```

produce:

```
Matriz ampliada inicial:
  9.00   3.00   4.00   1.00   0.00   0.00 
  4.00   3.00   4.00   0.00   1.00   0.00 
  1.00   1.00   1.00   0.00   0.00   1.00 

Procesando columna 0
Intercambiar fila 2 con 0
Matriz intercambiada
  1.00   1.00   1.00   0.00   0.00   1.00 
  4.00   3.00   4.00   0.00   1.00   0.00 
  9.00   3.00   4.00   1.00   0.00   0.00 

Ajuste para fila 1 es -4.0
Matriz ajustada
  1.00   1.00   1.00   0.00   0.00   1.00 
  0.00  -1.00   0.00   0.00   1.00  -4.00 
  9.00   3.00   4.00   1.00   0.00   0.00 

Ajuste para fila 2 es -9.0
Matriz ajustada
  1.00   1.00   1.00   0.00   0.00   1.00 
  0.00  -1.00   0.00   0.00   1.00  -4.00 
  0.00  -6.00  -5.00   1.00   0.00  -9.00 

Procesando columna 1
Ajuste para fila 2 es -6.0
Matriz ajustada
  1.00   1.00   1.00   0.00   0.00   1.00 
  0.00  -1.00   0.00   0.00   1.00  -4.00 
  0.00   0.00  -5.00   1.00  -6.00  15.00 

Procesando columna 2
Matriz triangulación superior
  1.00   1.00   1.00   0.00   0.00   1.00 
  0.00  -1.00   0.00   0.00   1.00  -4.00 
  0.00   0.00  -5.00   1.00  -6.00  15.00 

Procesando columna 1
Fila 0, factor 1.0
Ajustada
  1.00   0.00   1.00   0.00   1.00  -3.00 
  0.00  -1.00   0.00   0.00   1.00  -4.00 
  0.00   0.00  -5.00   1.00  -6.00  15.00 

Procesando columna 2
Fila 0, factor 0.2
Ajustada
  1.00   0.00   0.00   0.20  -0.20   0.00 
  0.00  -1.00   0.00   0.00   1.00  -4.00 
  0.00   0.00  -5.00   1.00  -6.00  15.00 

Fila 1, factor 0.0
Ajustada
  1.00   0.00   0.00   0.20  -0.20   0.00 
  0.00  -1.00   0.00   0.00   1.00  -4.00 
  0.00   0.00  -5.00   1.00  -6.00  15.00 

Matriz triangulación inferior
  1.00   0.00   0.00   0.20  -0.20   0.00 
  0.00  -1.00   0.00   0.00   1.00  -4.00 
  0.00   0.00  -5.00   1.00  -6.00  15.00 

Matriz identidad
  1.00   0.00   0.00   0.20  -0.20   0.00 
  0.00   1.00  -0.00  -0.00  -1.00   4.00 
  0.00   0.00   1.00  -0.20   1.20  -3.00 

Inversa
  0.20  -0.20   0.00 
 -0.00  -1.00   4.00 
 -0.20   1.20  -3.00
```